# How to move jar file from one folder to another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby script I have to copy one `jar` file from `lib` to a different location. Below is the piece of code where I am trying to do so:

```
FileUtils.mv("#{$HOME_PATH}/lib/myjar1.jar", "#{$HOME_PATH}")
```

But it is not able to move the `jar` file to destination. I am seeing the following error:

```
 No such file or directory - file:/home/path/lib/myjar1.jar or file:/home/path/myjar1.jar
```

I double checked that `myjar1.jar` is present in source directory. Not sure why I am seeing that error.

I also tried using `FileUtils.cp_r("#{$HOME_PATH}/lib/myjar1.jar", "#{$HOME_PATH}")` and I am seeing the following error: `unknown file type: file:/home/path/lib/myjar1.jar`.

Any guidance in copying or moving a jar file is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are starting from your home directory (hence the $HOME_PATH).  I prefer to use the given ENV hash in IRB.

In IRB this works in MAC OSX:

```
>> FileUtils.mv("#{ENV['HOME']}/Desktop/my.jar", "#{ENV['HOME']}")
0
```

The `FileUtils#mv` method returns 0 as that is the return code of the Unix version of mv which just means it was successful.